# Yarn: How to specify the path of the package.json file

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

With NPM you can `sudo npm --prefix /var/www...` to specify the path of a package.json file.

How can you achieve this with Yarn? I can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/4174 - or https://deploy-preview-774--yarnpkg.netlify.com/en/docs/cli/install#toc-yarn-install-cwd for the moment

Comment: Using `yarn install --cwd` solved my use case perfectly. Thanks

Comment: +1 I need to separate my dependencies into two package json files, one for packages on the registry, and one for my own packages not on the registry. This is because I'm using Google cloud functions, and it can only install packages from registry. Any non-registry packages must be installed locally and deployed with everything else.

Answer (score 15):

To run `yarn` command from any folder, you should specify path to working directory after `--cwd`. 
So to run `yarn build` for specific path you should run

```
yarn --cwd <path> build
```